# C# Events Dll Interface

Tags: c#

I have dlls sum and interface

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    string Name {get; }
    string GetDescription();

    double GetLastResult { get; }
    double Execute(double value1, double value2);

    event EventHandler OnExecute;

    void ExceptionTest(string input);
}

public class Sum : IPlugin
{      
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Sum"; }
    }

    public event EventHandler OnExecute;
}
```

How to make event like I take name of dll,event say that name was taken?

DLL loaded like this:

```
private PluginInterface.IPlugin LoadAssembly(string assemblyPath)
{
    string assembly = Path.GetFullPath(assemblyPath);
    Assembly ptrAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assembly);

    foreach (Type item in ptrAssembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (!item.IsClass) continue;
        if (item.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(PluginInterface.IPlugin)))
        {
            return (PluginInterface.IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(item);
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Invalid DLL, Interface not found!");
}

IPlugin currPlugin;
currPlugin = LoadAssembly("pathtodll");
MessageBox.Show(currPlugin.Name);
```

I tried to made event like this:

```
currPlugin.OnExecute += currPlugin_OnExecute; //subscribe to dll
void currPlugin_OnExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Event OnExecute triggered from DLL " + ((PluginInterface.IPlugin)sender).Name);
}
```

But i don't know what to do next
Please,help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need raise the event `OnExecute` inside `double Execute(double value1, double value2)` implementation.

This example is just for test.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //load the .exe assembly using reflection(just for testing)
        var currPlugin = LoadAssembly(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        Console.WriteLine(currPlugin.Name);
        currPlugin.OnExecute += currPlugin_OnExecute;
        currPlugin.Execute(10d, 20d);
    }

    private static void currPlugin_OnExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var plugin = (IPlugin) sender;

        Console.WriteLine("Event OnExecute triggered from DLL '{0}'", plugin.GetType().Assembly.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Event OnExecute -> {1}", plugin.Name, plugin.GetLastResult);
    }

    private static IPlugin LoadAssembly(string assemblyPath)
    {
        string assembly = Path.GetFullPath(assemblyPath);
        Assembly ptrAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assembly);

        foreach (Type item in ptrAssembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (!item.IsClass) continue;
            if (item.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof (IPlugin)))
            {
                return (IPlugin) Activator.CreateInstance(item);
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Invalid DLL, Interface not found!");
    }
}

public interface IPlugin
{
    string Name { get; }
    string GetDescription();

    double GetLastResult { get; }
    double Execute(double value1, double value2);

    event EventHandler OnExecute;

    void ExceptionTest(string input);
}

public class Sum : IPlugin
{
    private double _lastResult = double.NaN;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Sum"; }
    }

    public string GetDescription()
    {
        return "Plugin description";
    }

    public double GetLastResult
    {
        get { return _lastResult; }
    }

    public double Execute(double value1, double value2)
    {
        _lastResult = value1 + value2;
        OnExecuteInvoke();
        return _lastResult;
    }

    public event EventHandler OnExecute;

    protected virtual void OnExecuteInvoke()
    {
        var handler = OnExecute;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void ExceptionTest(string input)
    {
        throw new Exception(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`public interface IPlugin
{
    void Execute();
    event EventHandler OnExecute;
}
public class Sum : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute()
    {
       if (this.OnExecute != null)
           this.OnExecute(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    public event EventHandler OnExecute;
}
////////// use
Sum sum = new Sum();
Console.WriteLine("Before subscribe");
sum.Execute();
sum.OnExecute += new EventHandler(sum_OnExecute);
Console.WriteLine("After subscribe");
sum.Execute();`